# How to replace finding words with the different in each occurrence in VI/VIM editor ?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, text-editor, vi

For example, I have a text , 
10 3 4 2 10 , 4 ,10 ....

No I want to change each 10 with different words

I know  %s/10/replace-words/gc but it only let me replace interactively like yes/no but I want to change each occurrence of 10 with different words like replace1, 3, 4 , 2 , replace2, 4, replace3 ....

Comment: in sample shown, the replacement words have incremental numbers, is that what you need or replacement could be random?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replaces each occurence of `10` with `replace{index_of_match}`:

```
:let @a=1 | %s/10/\='replace'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

Replaces each occurence of `10` with a word from a predefined array:

```
:let b = ['foo', 'bar', 'vim'] | %s/10/\=(remove(b, 0))/g
```

Replaces each occurence of `10` with a word from a predefined array, and the index of the match:

```
:let @a=1 | let b = ['foo', 'bar', 'vim'] | %s/10/\=(b[@a-1]).(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

But since you have to type in any word anyway, the benefit of the second and third function this is minimal. See the answer from SpoonMeiser for the "manual" solution.

Update: As wished, the explanation for the regex part in the second example:

`%`= on every line in the document
`s/<search>/<replace>/g` = `s` means do a search & replace, `g` means replace every occurence.
`\=` interprets the following as code.
`remove(b, 0)` removes the element at index 0 of the list `b` and returns it.

so for the first occurrence. the line will be `%s/10/foo/g` the second time, the list is now only `['bar', 'vim']` so the line will be `%s/10/bar/g` and so on

*Note: This is a quick draft, and unlikely the best & cleanest way to achieve it, if somebody wants to improve it, feel free to add a comment*

Comment: in case if each replacing words are different ? and thanks man :)

Comment: ok thanks bro i'm new in vi so it would be great if you elaborate each terms used in this command

Comment: which one of the 3 here ? Are you familiar with coding ? then you should be able to find out what it does (http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/ is an excellent source, or google) if not, it is to much to explain. I would recommend learning the usage of vim first. But once you have a specific question to a part of the command here, i will gladly help you

Comment: in 3rd one you  created array right ? but i want to know the know more about regex part of 3rd example

Comment: yeah it is a list in vimscript not an array, but for this example it is the same. I've put the explanation in the answer.

Comment: now i fully got it. thank you very much for such great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a pattern to the words you want or would you want to type each word at each occurrence of the word you're replacing?

If I were replacing each instance of "10" with a different word, I'd probably do it somewhat manually:

```
/10
cw
<type word>ESC
ncw
<type word>ESC
ncw
<type word>ESC
```

Which doesn't seem too onerous, if each word is different and has to be typed separately anyway.

Comment: this throws errors  in my case and says "E486: Pattern not found: 10cw:

Comment: @rcShahi that is because it means `/10<CR>cw`. This is easy to forget, since it is clear for a vimuser that you are searching for 10