# renumber a column in a yaml file using any editor at all

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have a yaml file that has a long list of numbered fields in it.

```
 1:first
    .
    .     
22: this
23: that
24: somethingelse
22: this2
23: that2
24: somethingelse2
etc
```

I'm trying to get to

```
 1: first
     .
     .
     .
22: this
23: that
24: somethingelse
25: this2
26: that2
27: somethingelse2
```

What I need to do is renumber these fields starting at a defined number up to about 400 (multiple times per file).

There has to be a way to do this in either vim, atom or sublime but I'm struggling to find a way.

Incrementing the numbers seems to work in vim with ^X but I really need to take the number above the column I'm renumbering and add one to it and replace the text up to the : with that number. Its probably a regex issue to get the selection right and a macro to make it work, but I can't work it out.

Comment: please submit the desired output for your example above, it is unfortunaly not clear what you want.

Comment: I've discovered that :/\d\{1,3}:/ will select the number at the start of the line (including the :). Would a macro work from there?

Comment: You can use tool that is designed for numbering - `nl`. Delete all numbers (you can do that with visual block mode), then select all the file you want re-numbered and type `!nl -ba -w2 -s": "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here for details: [How to replace finding words with the different in each occurrence in VI/VIM editor ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539251/how-to-replace-finding-words-with-the-different-in-each-occurrence-in-vi-vim-edi/43539546#43539546)

Something like this should work:

```
:let @a=1 | %s/^\s*\zs\d\{1,3}\ze:/\=(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g
```

of course you can adapt @a to your needs. As you see, your `\d\{1,3}` is still used. But to make sure only the right part is matched, it looks for the beginning of the line. Furthermore it does not replace `:` but check for it. This is possible with `\zs` and `\ze`. see `:h \ze` for more info

Comment: Thank you Doctor, that worked. What I have also done is record a macro that yanks the number on the line above into a register, replaces the current number with it and then increments it with <CTL-A> and then moves down a line. Not as efficient as your solution though.