# Paste block multiple times with (increasing) numbering using vim

Tags: vim, yaml, text-editor

I have a block in a yaml file that I would like to yank and paste several times:

```
- probeNumber: 1
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.1]
```

Is it possible to automatically increment the value of `probeNumber` and `probeLocation` in each block? Like so:

```
- probeNumber: 1
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.1]

- probeNumber: 2
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.15]

- probeNumber: 3
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.20]
```

`probeLocation` is not an integer, it is incremented by a fixed value in each block (0.05). I need 1000 or so of these blocks so doing this manually is not feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a template in your text file, suppose starting with line 1.

```
- probeNumber: 1
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.1]

- probeNumber: 1
  probeLocation: [0, 0, 0.1]

...repeat the number as you want, e.g. copy the first block and do 100p for 100 copy
```

Then use following command to update the value:
For updating `probeNumber`

```
:%s!1$!\=printf("%d", line('.')/3+1)!g
```

For updating `probeLocation`

```
:%s!0\.1!\=printf("%0.2f", 0.10+(line('.')/3)*0.05)!g
```

Where `0.10` is the initial value, `0.05` is the increment.

Thank for SergioAraujo pointing out mistake of the original expression
`:%s!0\.1$!\=printf("0.%d", 10+(line('.')/3)*5)!g`
Which fails as the replaced value will never be greater than 1.

The main idea is to use `line` function to update the value, you may check [Replace a pattern with current line number](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/replace-a-pattern-with-current-line-number) and [Insert line numbers](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert_line_numbers) for more details.

Comment: Well this only works if the blocks are the same height (which is the case here). A more general solution would be something like `:let @a=1 | %s/<line>/\='replace'.(@a+setreg('a',@a+1))/g` more on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539251/how-to-replace-finding-words-with-the-different-in-each-occurrence-in-vi-vim-edi/43539546#43539546 or here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/how-to-replace-each-match-with-incrementing-counter/12869#12869

Comment: I think the first substitution could be shorter: `:%s,\d\+$,\=(line('.')/3+1)`

Comment: It seems like the `probeLocation` lines are been added with `0.05` just after the dot. Let me know if I am wrong!

Comment: @SergioAraujo, thx for pointing out the error, I have updated the expression.

Comment: @mulligatawny soup, please check my updated answer as I made a mistake in the original expression for probe location.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out another way of solving this issue:

If you have the three first lines on the clipboard, which means the two first lines and a blank line you could create the file with this:

```
:for i in range(999) | silent! 0put + | endfor
```

In order to increase probeNumber lines:

```
:let c=1 | g/\d\+$/ s//\=c/ | let c+=1
```

Now the lines with probeLocation:

```
:let c=0.10 | g/0\.1\ze]/ s//\=printf("%0.2f", c)/ | let c+=0.05
```